# C++ reading from a text file into a array and then into another text file

Tags: c++, arrays

integers.txt has the following numbers: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int numbers[10];
  int i;
  ofstream outf;
  outf.open("integers.txt");
  ifstream inf;
  inf.open("in.txt");
  for(int i = 0; i < numbers[i]; i++);
  {
    outf >> numbers[10];

  }
  inf << numbers[10];
  outf.close();
  inf.close();
  return 0;
}
```

I want the program to output the integers from integers.txt file to an array and from the array to in.txt file. I get the following error: `no match for 'operator>>' in 'outf >> numbers[10]'`

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: Use spaces when formatting the code, tabs don't fare well.

Answer (score 2):

You have swapped your file stream types.

You want to read in from integers.txt, but you opened an `ofstream` on the file. An `ofstream` only lets you *output* to the file, not read from it, and therefore only has the `<<` operator defined, not `>>`. You want to open an `ifstream` on integers.txt so that you can read input from the file, and probably open an `ofstream` on in.txt.

```
ifstream inf;
inf.open("integers.txt");
ofstream outf;
outf.open("in.txt")

//read in from inf (aka integers.txt)
//output to outf (aka in.txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using `ifstream` and `ofsteam` correctly. `ifstream` is for reading and `ofstream` is for writing the content to the file. However there are some more issues in your code i.e.

- Using an uninitialized array of `numbers`
- Using an uninitialized variable i
- Trying to access the array[size] (`numbers[10]`) it gives an error that `stack around the variable 'numbers' is corrupted`

Following code will do the task for you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int numbers[10] = {0};
  int i = 0;
  ofstream outf;
  outf.open("in.txt");

  ifstream inf;
  inf.open("integers.txt");
  while (inf >> numbers[i])
  {
    inf >> numbers[i];
    outf << " " << numbers[i];
    i++;
  }
  outf.close();
  inf.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: My understanding is that `while (!inf.eof())` should be replaced by `while (inf >> numbers[i])`.  See [why eof is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Correction appreciated :)

Comment: Isn't while more useful when I don't know how many integers are in a file ? But anyway thanks.

Comment: @ParanoidParrot You are right, that is why I used `while` loop but it will not work unless you use dynamic memory for storing the integers, you can use `vectors` with a `while` loop when you do not know the exact number of integers in the file. You may accept the answer if you really find it useful.